# Measure React DOM node on resize with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to measure a React DOM node on the window resize event. I've used the example on the [React hooks-faq](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node), but it only happens for the first render. If I add a `useEffect` to listen for the resize, the callback doesn't get called?

```
function MeasureExample() {
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

    const measuredRef = useCallback(node => {
        if (node !== null) {
            setHeight(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);
        }
    }, []);


    // Adding this effect doesn't re-calculate the height???
    useEffect(() => {

        window.addEventListener("resize", measuredRef);

        return (): void => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", measuredRef);
        };

    }, [height])

    return (
        <>
            <h1 ref={measuredRef}>Hello, world</h1>
            <h2>The above header is {Math.round(height)}px tall</h2>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: it means value of the `height` state is not changing. `console.log(height)` ? what you are getting ? is it changing ?

Comment: Adding and removing the event listener every time the screen height changes seems a tad wasteful.  This is maybe one of those rare occasions passing `[]` makes sense.  Also personally I would split this into 2 components, one component for doing your resize event capture, and then pass the height down as a prop.

Answer (score 12):

here is another solution.

```
function MeasureExample() {
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
    const [node, setNode] = useState(null);

    const measuredRef = useCallback(node => {
        if (node !== null) {
            setNode(node);
        }
    }, []);
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if(node){
         const measure = () => {
           setSize(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);
         }
        
         window.addEventListener("resize", measure );

         return () => {
           window.removeEventListener("resize", measure );
         };
       }
    }, [node])

    return (
        <>
            <h1 ref={measuredRef}>Hello, world</h1>
            <h2>The above header is {Math.round(height)}px tall</h2>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would extract out the part of listening for resize events.  The advantage is it can be used again for something else.

Because resizing is `async`, one trick with React is to make the children into a functional return instead of just returning JSX.  You can then make your CaptureResize component call the function instead to get it's JSX, and at the same time pass the size to this function.

Below is an example..

```js
const {useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState} = React;

function CaptureResize(props) {
  const {captureRef} = props;
  function updateSize() {
    setSize(captureRef.current.getBoundingClientRect());
  }
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    updateSize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateSize);
    return () => 
      window.removeEventListener("resize", updateSize);
  }, []);
  const [size, setSize] = useState({});
  return props.children(size)
}

function Test() {
  const c = useRef(null);
  return <CaptureResize captureRef={c}>
    {(size) => <React.Fragment>
      <h1 ref={c}>Header 1, Resize window to make this go onto diffrent no. of lines</h1>
      <div>height of header = {size.height}px</div>
    </React.Fragment>}
  </CaptureResize>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<React.Fragment>
  <Test/>
</React.Fragment>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="mount"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Measure window screen size and also resize using react hooks**

```
import React from 'react';

function useWindowDimensions() {
  const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(window.innerWidth);
  const [height, setHeight] = React.useState(window.innerHeight);

  React.useState(() => {
    const listener = () => {
      setWidth(window.innerWidth)
      setHeight(window.innerHeight)
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', listener);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', listener);
    }
  })

  return {
    width,
    height,
  }
}


function App() {
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions()
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>width: {width}</h2>
      <h2>height: {height}</h2>
      <p>Resize the window.</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you! Great answer to make a custom hook...

Now how would you do this in NextJs?